# Where do web page style-specific questions belong?

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

I have some questions relating to ways to style and display information within a web application a well as how to structure some of the user interactions.

Where is the best place to ask these types of questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for UI design suggestions, try fledgling SE site [User Interface](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

For the style half of your question, you could try [Doctype](http://www.doctype.com/), which isn't part of the Stack Exchange network but was modeled after SO a while back — with official approval — and has some design-specific features.

For the UI side of things, Zeke was right about [the UI beta](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).